# (grunt) shell: Command to open default editor

Tags: node.js, git, shell, gruntjs, grunt-shell

Is it possible to run the default editor (which is set for git) using `grunt-shell` to open and edit an file (on ubuntu)?

In my attempt it is running sublime, but every local system is using a different editor...

```
grunt.initConfig({
  shell: {
    changelog: {
      options: {
        stdinRawMode: true
      },
      command: 'subl -w CHANGELOG.md'
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
command: '`git var GIT_EDITOR` CHANGELOG.md'
```

`git var GIT_EDITOR` get the configured editor — from the environment var, from local or global config, or fallback to other environment variables (`VISUAL/EDITOR`) or default `vi`.